# Updating user meta adds string count to value?

Tags: php, forms, plugin-gravity-forms, phpmyadmin

I am using Gravity Forms to update user meta. The user meta has to be serialized for another plugin, so I have to catch the value and convert it using the `gform_pre_submission` action before it gets uploaded to the database. It is converting just fine (`a:1:{i:0;s:2:"62";}`), and the entries on Gravity Forms show up exactly as I want. The problem is, when I look at the usermeta values in my phpMyAdmin, they are being stored with the string length first (ie. `s:19:"a:1:{i:0;s:2:"62";}";`), and I'm trying to get rid of that.

The problem seems to be in the conversion somewhere, as the string length doesn't show up if I don't convert it. Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_13', 'serialize_user_tags' );
function serialize_user_tags( $form ) {
    $org_type_choice = rgpost( 'input_6' );
    $job_type_choice = rgpost( 'input_5' );
    $interest_choices = rgpost( 'input_7' );

    $string_org = 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"'.$org_type_choice.'";}';
    $string_job = 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"'.$job_type_choice.'";}';
    
    if (!is_array($interest_choices)){
        $string_int = 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"'.$interest_choices.'";}';
    } else {
        $count_int = count($interest_choices);
        $string_int = 'a:'.$count_int.':{';
        $i_counter_int = 0;
        foreach ($interest_choices as $interest_choice) {
            $string_int .= 'i:'.$i_counter_int.';s:2:"'.$interest_choice.'";';
            $i_counter_int++;
        }
        $string_int .= '}';
    }
    
    $_POST['input_6'] = $string_org;
    $_POST['input_5'] = $string_job;
    $_POST['input_7'] = $string_int;
}
```

Comment: That structure is serialized PHP, the output of the `serialize` function, you shouldn't be constructing it manually via strings, I suspect it's then being serialized a second time leading to double serialized data. I'd also strongly advise against modifying the `$_POST` superglobal array, no HTML form will ever produce that kind of output. Fundamentally, this solution to your problem doesn't work, you should how to do what you were originally trying to do, not how to fix the solution, aka how to update user meta when a gravity form is submitted

Comment: Gravity Forms support told me to use `$_POST`. Also, if I do `$_POST['input_6'] = $org_type_choice;` directly, it shows up in my phpMyAdmin as `62`. If I do `$_POST['input_6'] = serialize($org_type_choice);` I get `s:9:"s:2:"62";";` So why is it suddenly serializing it twice? And if you have a better solution, can you please share in an answer?

Comment: to be honest I don't know, this question requires a hefty amount of Gravity Forms specific expertise to understand what's going on and how that filter is supposed to work. You should go back to GF support or ask a GF developer or in one of the GF communities, 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here